# Excel Vba dictionary not looped

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Before]

[image: What i want]

I have this code that is supposed to iterate through my folder and add the file names into the dictionary, however after adding my extraction code inside this for loop, only data from the last file in the folder will be extracted because everytime it collects data from the next file, it will overwrite the row and column "A2:M2" and not continue adding on.

UPDATED

```
Public Dict As Object
Sub EEE()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, ofile As Object

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\file\")

If Dict Is Nothing Then
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dict.Add Key:="filename", Item:=ofile
End If

For Each ofile In oFolder.Files
    If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)) Then

    Dim basePath As Variant
    basePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\file\"

             Dim baseFolder As Scripting.Folder
        With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
            Set baseFolder = .GetFolder(basePath)
        End With


            Dim file As Scripting.file
            For Each file In baseFolder.Files

            Dim a As Range

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
            Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(file.path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Book1"
            Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Book1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

            Dim LastRow As Long
                LastRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

            wks.Cells(LastRow, 6).value = file.Name

        Set a = wksData.Columns("A:A").Find("  test1234         : ", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
        wks.Cells(LastRow, 1) = Split(a.value, ":")(1)
        End If

                wkbData.Close False

                Range("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                Range("A1").AutoFilter

        Debug.Print "A: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
        Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1
                Next file

    Else
        'skip
        Debug.Print "E: " & oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)

    End If

Next ofile

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You can add a counter variable and increment it with each file `counter = counter + 1` and then when you write the values in this line: `wks.Cells(LastRow, 1)` change the 1 with the counter. But I suggest you to first try to organize your code as it’s kind of tangled.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module (you should *always* use that throughout your modules).  What is `wks` in your code? Where is it declared/populated?  Also do not use Range() or Cells() without an explicit worksheet qualifier - it will make your code liable to failure if the wrong sheet happens to be active when you expect some other sheet to be the one you operate on.

Comment: @TimWilliams actually the process code doesn't really matter, i'm trying to get rid of the error `Key is associated with an element of this collection` i have for loop for the dictionary and inside it i need to have another for loop in order for me to extract data from all the files, without the for loop, only one file can be extracted out.

Comment: If that's the error your getting then it would be super-useful for you to include that in your posted question?  Exactly where does that error occur?  This looks like your fourth or fifth posting of pretty much the same question, so either stick with this one or expect folks to stop being helpful at some point

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry my bad, i have updated the code and the error occurs at this line `Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1`

Comment: What if you move `Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1` up to immediately following `If Not Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)) Then` ?  It's difficult to see why this might be a problem though - if you use `Exists` to test before adding the key, I've never seen that fail - unless you're recycling `ofile` in some code you've not included....

Comment: @TimWilliams it is now able to have more rows of data, however the rows of data are all from one file e.g file 11 which means it was only able to extract data from one file into 10 rows ... may i know what you might mean by recycling `oFile`? actually the 2 for loops are looping for the same folder, might that be the cause of the error?

Comment: Maybe update your post with your full code?  We can't guess about code you don't post.

Comment: @TimWilliams i have updated it once again, really sorry if the code is an extreme mess, but hopefully the error can be found and solved...  thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I can't trouble-shoot that amount of code - you will need to pare it right back, get a simpler version working, and then add back code and debug as you go.

Comment: @TimWilliams actually the process code really doesn't matter much... i have updated the code to the simpler version it's the problem between the 2 for loops... somehow they can't work together with each other,  if i put `Dict.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile), 1` immediately following `Dict.Exists(oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)) Then` it will only add one filename into the dictionary after i finish extracting all files in folder, meaning infinite loops if there were 100 files... and if i were to place it below before the `Next file` it wouldn't even work...

Comment: Why are you looping through the same folder using two nested loops?  What is the purpose of processing all these file multiple times?

Comment: You check in the *outer* `ofile` loop to see if the filename is already in `Dict`, but you don't do that in the inner `file` loop, where you're trying to add `oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)` - you should move that up to the outer loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams the purpose of processing all these files multiple times is to extract data from all files.  sorry what do you mean by moving the inner file loop up to the outer loop? i have updated the question with images, hopefully you can understand what i am trying to do... without the for loop it would be like the `before` picture but what i am looking for is something like the after picture

Comment: Your `ofile` loop already processes every file in the folder -you *do not need* another inner loop (your `file` loop) which processes these same files.  I can't add anything to what I've already pointed out.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah yes i know there isn't the need and i would like to remove it as well but without the for loop inside the `ofile` loop , somehow the files will be succesfully added into the dictionary yes but data extracted will be constantly getting overwrited by the next file e.g range `A2:M2` consists of data from file1 however as it proceeds on to file2, it overwrites data from file 1 and on the same range `A2:M2` when its supposed to be continuing onto range `A3:M3` and so on...

Comment: The outer loop will process all files - if that's not happening then adding a second loop is not the answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams ahh yes... if possible could you share me any advices on what to do instead of adding a second loop?

Comment: Remove the second loop and post a new question explaining your problem, with a minimum set of code to reproduce the problem, and a full description of the issue you're having, along with any error messages.